# ROS Arch linux wiki question

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a question about the following peice of code in http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch

```
# ROS
indigo() {
  source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/your/your/package/path:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
  export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
  alias python=/usr/bin/python2

  # Gazebo
  source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
}
```

In this i did not understand the environment variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Is is needed ? What is the role of it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194189/ros-arch-linux-wiki-question/) by [neoDEH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20383/neodeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is used to find packages to build from source.

I suggest you read about the filesystem concepts [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts)
it's also documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0